# How to find/loop value in array of List in ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I got something like this:

```
list = [{color= "blue"; number = 1}, {color= "red"; number = 2}, {color= "orange"; number = 3}]
```

And i need to find if for example a color exists in my list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "array of list". What you have is a list of records.

To find the first item in a list given some predicate you can use `List.find`:

```
List.find (fun item -> item.color = "red") list
```

There's also `List.find_opt` which returns an `option` instead of raising an exception when no item is found, and `List.find_all` which will return a list of *all* items matching the predicate.

See the [`List` module reference](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) for more.